# The relation between the radiuses...

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Find $\frac{R}{r}$ where $R$ is the radius of the circumscribed circle of a trapezoid and $r$ is the radius of the inscribed circle of this trapezoid.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Link an image of the diagram and someone might give you a hint.

Comment: What information do you have from which you want to compute that fraction? Coordinates of the corners, lengths of the edges, or something else entirely?

Comment: I only have the radiuses, that's all. I know it may be weird but it's really so.

Comment: Given $R$ and $r$, finding $\frac Rr$ is not much of a geometric question; it's a simple fraction. So there must be something wrong here. Perhaps you need to find some properties of the trapezoid given the radiuses or their fraction? Or you need to determine the set possible ratios? By the way, the image suggests that the center of the circumcircle might be the same as for the incircle (interpreting the blue line as an intended radius) or the midpoint of $AD$. Is either stated in your question?

Comment: It's a bicentric trapezoid, excuse me I didn't mentioned. And the problem is not wrong, I know that the final solution should be a nice one, and also, what's the most important- it's an exact value , something of a fraction or square root.

Comment: @JohnG.: I can construct a bicentric isosceles trapezoid with any ratio from $\sqrt2$ (for the square) to infinity (for sides with infinitesimal slope). So I don't know what exact value you might be referring to, unless you have further constraints which I missed or which are not included in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm *assuming* that you are looking for an isosceles bicentric trapezoid where the outcenter lies on the edge $AD$, since your figure looks that way. In that case you get

$$\frac Rr=1+\sqrt2$$

[image: Figure of construction]

You can deduce this by starting with a right isosceles triangle:

$$A=(1,0)\qquad D=(0,1)\qquad E=(0,0)$$

Then the outcircle will have radius

$$R=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$

and the incircle will have radius

$$r=1-\frac1{\sqrt2}$$

which you can check by verifying that the incircle center $I=(r,r)$ has distance $r$ from the outcircle center $O=(\frac12,\frac12)$. You can turn this triangle into an isosceles trapezoid by cutting away the tip, i.e. by intersecting $OE$ with the incircle, resulting in point $F$, and then constructing a line through $F$ parallel to $AD$. But since you already have the circles, you can simply skip this and instead compute your fraction.